# Multiple Define Error in XPages CKEditor since Domino Version 10

Tags: ckeditor, xpages, lotus-domino, hcl

We're using XPages since a couple of years for 3 business applications we developped for a customer. CKEditor is playing a strategic role for one of the applications and we customized toolbar and skin. Since V10 of Domino we get a "mutlipleDefine" error as soon as we load an XPage with a CKEditor component. Even in a test app with only one XPage containing only a basic richttext item, no other external libraries, etc.

```
dojo.js:formatted:1317 Error: multipleDefine
    at _f (dojo.js:formatted:47)
    at _f9 (dojo.js:formatted:1074)
    at def (dojo.js:formatted:1267)
    at xspCKEditor-web-config.js:5
```

This error didn't have any impacts for the moment. But our customer now wants to add external plugins to the CKEditor and this doesn't work anymore. Same Database with extensions for CKEditor on a server V9 is working as a charm but not a server V10. The external plugins are stored in the WebContent Folder of the application. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error is known by HCL and tracked as PALTBNXPQ4. See this answer from Paul Albright who has created the problem report:
https://hclpnpsupport.hcltech.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=2ae1909d1bc91050a67e9759bc4bcbb4&anchor=answer_651d98d91b8d1050a67e9759bc4bcbf2&view_source=searchResult

I see the same `multipleDefine` error and I am using external plugins too but I have no issues with external plugins.

Comment: ok - as you told me it's possible,I tried hard again and found a solution:

Until Domino9 I was able to set extra Plugins by my JS Code only

CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins "tabletoolstoolbar,devtools,copyformatting,...."

Now with Domino10 I must set extra Plugins in the dojo attributes of my richtextfield in my xPage 

<xp:dojoAttribute name="extraPlugins"  value="tabletoolstoolbar,devtools,copyformatting,...">       </xp:dojoAttribute>

Now it's working again ...

Comment: Great that you found a solution. I am also setting extraPlugins using xp:dojoAttribute